# How to avoid adding rows to SQLAlchemy if value didn't change since last entry?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm going to track the evolution of some values with a database via SQLAlchemy: I get them as a sequence of (key, value) pairs and I expect the values for each key to change rarely.

I'm using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) with [declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html), the model looks like:

```
class Item(Base):
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)
    key       = Column(Unicode(16))
    value     = Column(something...)
```

I'd like to store rows like (timestamp, key, value) in the database and avoid storing new entries if the value didn't change since the last one recorded, while keeping the whole history of past values. In pseudo python:

```
for foo in new_items:
    query = session.query(Item).filter_by(key=foo.key)
    latest = query.order_by(Item.timestamp.desc()).first()
    if foo.value == latest.value:
        continue    # nothing changed, ignore the new item
    else:
        session.add(foo)
session.commit()
```

Should I go with a naive approach like the one above? It somehow strikes me as not-good-looking code. At least I'd maybe add the test as a method on Item.

Is there some better way to do that? Better does not necessarily mean quicker, could be just more pythonic or better looking code.

Comment: Since you're the one adding the items, why not just keep track of the last one you added rather than querying the database for it each time? If you need this to work across multiple runs, initialize the "last item added" variable from the database once at the beginning of your script.

Comment: @kindall, thanks for the suggestion, and yes it's across multiple run (1 run = 1 batch of INSERTs). I don't foresee many variants of the algorithm (either you read-and-compare one key at a time, or you read out all the latest in a single batch and then compare one at a time, like your proposal) - I'm more interested in possible coding patterns for this: eg. should the Item instance query its class out of the db to compare timestamps? maybe a class method is better? or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware of two ways to do that. There's your approach:

```
if value not in database:
    session.add(value)
session.commit()
```

or

```
try:
    session.add(value)
    session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
```

The first one has a race condition. I tend to use the second pattern.